# Is there a way to sort an array with nullable properties in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting, null

Here is my code:

```
export function getExpertTitle(
  experiences: Array<{
    title?: string | null;
    description?: string | null;
    endDate?: Date | null;
  }> | null
) {
  const emptyExperience = {
    title: null,
    description: null,
    endDate: null
  };

  let currentExperience = experiences && experiences[0];
  
  // Here is were i start to have the error
  // Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.ts(2533)  

  for (let i = 0, l = experiences && experiences.length; i < (!isNullOrUndefined(l) && l); i++) {
    if (isNullOrUndefined(experiences && experiences[i].endDate)) {
      currentExperience = experiences && experiences[i];
    } else if ((!isNullOrUndefined(currentExperience) && currentExperience.endDate.getTime()) > Date.now()) {
      currentExperience = experiences && experiences[i];
    }
  }
```

So, what I want to do is compare the *experiences* array and sort them by date using the *endDate* property, and I want to set the *currentExperience* as the latest experience. Also if *endDate* property is 'null' the experience is still ongoing, that makes it the *currentExperience* by default.

I was thinking the **for** loop can look like this, but I'm still getting the error:

```
  for (let i = 0, l = experiences.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (isNullOrUndefined(experiences[i].endDate)){
      currentExperience = experiences && experiences[i];
      break;
    }
    else if (experiences[i].endDate?.getTime() > currentExperience.endDate.getTime()) {
      currentExperience = experiences && experiences[i];
    }
  }
```

I'm still working on this, if I get to the solution I'll post it.
In the meanwhile any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Based on the error, specifically `ts(2533)`, and also that you have type definitions, this should be a Typescript question (rather than Javascript). I recommend changing the tags to match this.

Comment: Thanks! I'll update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error is that your type definition for the array says any entry might be null:

```ts
experiences: Array<{
    title?: string | null;
    description?: string | null;
    endDate?: Date | null;
  }> | null // <------------------ HERE
```

To filter out the `null` values, you could use something like

```
experiences.filter(x => x !== null) as Array<{
  title?: string | null;
  description?: string | null;
  endDate?: Date | null; }> // array cannot contain null, only objects with null properties
```

but from what your code is doing I think you would prefer something like this in your for-loop:

```ts
  for (let i = 0, l = experiences.length; i < l; i++) {
    // below is now true if the object is null
    if (isNullOrUndefined(experiences && experiences[i] && experiences[i].endDate)){
      currentExperience = experiences && experiences[i];
      break;
    }
    // ...
  }
```